# Running source code from secondary drive in Ubuntu problems

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I'm dual booting OSX and Ubuntu on my older macbook pro, using a secondary HDD installed in the optical bay as a shared data folder. It's formatted as a non Journaled HFS+, and i changed my UID in ubuntu to 501 to match my osx uid. Everything seemed to work fine, but when trying to run some code in eclipse, it threw an error and would not execute. If I move my workspace  into my home folder, it works fine. I'm assuming it has to do with how the secondary drive is mounted. I added the following line to /etc/fstab for it to auto mount on startup.

```
 /dev/sdb3 /media/ShareData auto rw,user,auto 0 0
```

Output from mount

```
 /dev/sdb3 on /media/ShareData type hfsplus (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8,user)
```

I've only bee using Ubuntu for 2 weeks so I'm a total beginner. What do i need to change in order for this to work? Thanks!!

EDIT: so when i

```
 sudo mount -0 exec /dev/sdb3 /media/ShareData
```

it works now, does this permanently change its setting? if now how can I add this into the fstab setting to mount it with exec privileges ?

Comment: What is the output of the `mount` command (with no arguments)? I don't have experience with HFS+, but my guess is that the `user` mount option implicitly causes it to be mounted `noexec`. See for example [My HFS+ (hfsplus) partition won't mount with exec permissions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90129/my-hfs-hfsplus-partition-wont-mount-with-exec-permissions)

Comment: /dev/sdb3 on /media/jony/ShareData type hfsplus    (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8,user)

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was adding exec to the fstab config, as @steeldriver pointed out, it was defaulting to noexec

```
/dev/sdb3 /media/ShareData auto rw,user,exec,auto 0 0
```

Now it automounts and I can use my workspace again! : )